# How to assign Combo Box's selected item property to .rdlc text box?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, desktop-application

I want to display the type of bill in my report.

For that I have put the combo box in data entry form(Form1) which enables user to select the type of copy whether it is original,duplicate or triplicate.
I want to assign the selected value of the combo box(of Form1) to the text box which resides under the report(.rdlc file)
How to assign the control's property to the text box inside the report?

Please help.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This is what you can do:

Step 1: Create a parameter in `RDLC` Report
Step 2: Place the parameter where you want in the `RDLC` Input Textbox property
Step 3: Type the below code in `codebehind` page
Step 4: Pass the parameter value when you redirect the Report page

```
ReportParameterCollection reportParameters = new ReportParameterCollection();
reportParameters.Add(new ReportParameter("ParameterName", "Value"));
this.reportViewer.LocalReport.SetParameters(reportParameters);
```

> So whats happening is you are setting a parameter for your `textbox` in `.rdlc` and assigning the value to it programmatically.

Comment: :)...add rdlc and reportviewer tag along so that you will get a quicker reply for rdlc reporting related issues